# How to graph 3-D graph on top of a contour plot and a gradient vector field in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, graphing, wolframalpha

I'm trying to graph a 3-D graph over a contour graph and a gradient vector field (on the same graph) from {x,-2,2} and {y,-2,2}, in Wolfram Mathematica, for the function

```
h(x,y)= −2xe^((−x^2)*(−y^2))
```

The code I've been given is:

```
GradVectorField := VectorPlot[{hx[x,y], hy[x,y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}]
contour := ContourPlot[h[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}, PlotLegends −> Automatic, ContourLabels −> False]
Show[contour, GradVectorField , PlotLabel −> "title"]
```

which works in giving a gradient vector field over a contour plot

From this I thought I needed to add a function for the 3-D graph and call it in the "Show" function with the other two graphs. This is the code I tried:

```
h[x_,y_]:=(-2)*x*e^((-x^2)*(-y^2))
GradVectorField := VectorPlot[{hx[x,y], hy[x,y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}]
contour := ContourPlot[h[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}, PlotLegends->Automatic,ContourLabels->False]
threeDGraph :=Plot3D[{h[x, y]},{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AxesLabel->{x, y, z}, PlotRange->Automatic,PlotLegends->"Expressions",PlotLabel->"h[x,y]"]
Show[contour, GradVectorField ,threeDGraph, PlotLabel->"title"]
```

The above code gave a bunch of errors saying it could not combine the two different graph formats (2D and 3D and vectors). What am I missing?

Comment: You can cast your 2D data to 3D by taking the constructed graphics objects and adding `0` to the end of all the data. This can be done efficiently using `2` as the final argument of `Join` along with `ConstantArray[0, {numPoints, 1}]` along with a well-constructed `ReplaceAll`. These objects can then be inserted into the 3D plot using `Epilog` to get them to lie below the 3D data.

Comment: Thank you b3m2a1!